# Dropdown field doesn't read html entities

Tags: html, css, hex

I added some hex-dec code to show ratings by stars. It works elsewhere on the website but it doesn't show up in the drop down. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do `&#9733;`, `&#9734;`, `&#x2605;` and `&#x2606;` work?